# Date not displaying properly in JS dates app

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to make a simple JS calendar which will indicate the current date and then 90 dates after this date. I want it to be displayed as, example: Monday, May 6, 2019 -and- Sunday August 4, 2019. Can you tell me why my second date is displaying differently? Thank you! (I've attached the html file with the code).

I am able to set both dates to display like: 05/06/2019 and 08/04/2019, but when I attempt to change and use the arrays to display to the above syntax, the second date does not display correctly.

I have created a JS Fiddle that shows the code and the result, here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Catja_M/68q0s7fy/2/

```
var now = new Date();
var days = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
var months = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();
function fourdigits(number) {
return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;}
today=days[now.getDay()] + ", " +
months[now.getMonth()] + " " +
date + ", " +
(fourdigits(now.getYear()));     
document.write(today);

var now = new Date();
var days = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
var months = new
```

Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');

```
var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();
function fourdigits(number) {
return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;}
var today=new Date()
new Date(days[now.getDay()] + ", " +
months[now.getMonth()] + " " +
date + ", " +
(fourdigits(now.getYear())));

today.setDate(today.getDate()+90)   
document.write(today);
```

Looking to achieve both dates to display the same: Monday, May 6, 2019.

Comment: `document.write(today)` ... uses `Date#toString` method, which outputs `Mon Aug 05 2019 02:10:55 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time) `

Comment: @JaromandaX But, both methods use document.write(today) yet the first one displays the format I'm looking for: Monday, May 6, 2019. I'm not sure why the second one isn't doing this?

Comment: The Date constructor is only guaranteed to accept strings in ISO 8601 format, which yours aren't. Use integers per the docs. Or format your datestrings properly. Or use a library that does it for you.

Comment: @Catja - but one `today` is `days[now.getDay()] + ", " +` etc (i.e. a string you build up), in the second code, today is a `Date` object `var today=new Date()` ... the code `new Date(days[now.getDay()] + ", " +
        months[now.getMonth()] + " " +
        date + ", " +
          (fourdigits(now.getYear())));` on the new line does nothing in the second script

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks @Jared Smith

Comment: @Catja no problem. Always remember: if something isn't working the way you think it should, double-check that your understanding of the thing is correct. That goes double if you yourself are the one who wrote the thing in the first place :)

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, I wrote it. I had originally wrote it to display: 05/10/2019 for both dates. And, my code worked for both dates this way. But, then when I tried to convert both to displaying in May 10, 2019 format, I couldn't figure out what went wrong with the second date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
var today=new Date()
new Date(days[now.getDay()] + ", " +
months[now.getMonth()] + " " +
date + ", " +
(fourdigits(now.getYear())));

today.setDate(today.getDate()+90)   
document.write(today);
```

to:

```
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 90)  //this returns a total millis number not a "date", it needs to be converted to day/month/year

var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "") + now.getDate();
function fourdigits(number) {
    return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
}
var today = days[now.getDay()] + ", " + months[now.getMonth()] + " " + date + ", " +  fourdigits(now.getYear());
document.write(today);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JDunken! I appreciate you taking the time to show me the code you used.